# TWebBrowser через прокси

Tags: delphi, прокси

Не работает TWebBrowser через прокси. Прокси внутренней (локальной) сети предприятия. Код вида

```
procedure proxy_go(proxy: string);
var proxy_info : PInternetProxyInfo;
begin
New (proxy_info);
proxy_info^.dwAccessType := INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY;
proxy_info^.lpszProxy := PChar(proxy);
proxy_info^.lpszProxyBypass := PChar('');
UrlMkSetSessionOption(INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, proxy_info, SizeOf(Internet_Proxy_Info), 0);
Dispose(proxy_info);
end;
```

не помогает.

Comment: кнопочка с циферками (5я слева) помогает отредактировать код

Comment: Сразу вопрос: что возвращает UrlMkSetSessionOption?

Comment: UrlMkSetSessionOption=0